# BQ.ML Export Model is Greyed-Out, i.e., CAN'T EXPORT

Tags: google-bigquery, export

I've exported models in BQ.ML and not run into this issue.  I have enough in my billing account, so I don't know why when I'm in the BQ.ML interface, have built a successful model, it won't allow me to export my model.  Don't see any help literature online either.  Time sensitive, help is appreciated!